# How Layout Parameters work with constraints? Are they necessary?

Tags: android, layout, constraints

I've trying to understand `ConstraintLayout` in Android, but unfortunately its behaviour differ a lot from the the `ConstraintLayout` in Swift. It really confuses me.

Long story short: Changing the comment line bellow doesn't seems to make any difference. The constrains seems to always override the view size even if LayoutParams is not set to `MATCH_CONSTRAINT`.

```
        LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                HEIGHT
        );

        mView = new ConstraintLayout(getContext());
        mView.setId(View.generateViewId());
        mView.setLayoutParams(params);
        addView(mView);

        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams cParams;
        cParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
//                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
//                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
//                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
//                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                HEIGHT - 2*PADDING,
                HEIGHT - 2*PADDING
        );

        mText = new TextView(getContext());
        mText.setId(View.generateViewId());
        mText.setText("Title");
        mText.setTextSize(30);
        mText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
//        mText.setLayoutParams(cParams);
        mText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        mText.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        mView.addView(mText);

        set = new ConstraintSet();

        set.connect(mText.getId(), ConstraintSet.START, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.START, PADDING);
        set.connect(mText.getId(), ConstraintSet.TOP, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.TOP, PADDING);
        set.connect(mText.getId(), ConstraintSet.END, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.END, PADDING); //Always needed
        set.connect(mText.getId(), ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, ConstraintSet.PARENT_ID, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, PADDING); //Always needed

        set.applyTo(mView);
```

Do I need to set `LayoutParams` when using constraint layout? If so, why?

Is it possible to set the size of my view manually with LayoutParams and just use the `ConstrainSet.connect` twice, e.g., with `START` and `TOP`? I've tried it and it didn't work.